# Endpoint returning a 404

Tags: plugin-development

Hi I've built a wordpress plugin using a class.
I'm sure all names (functies, urls, etc are correct.
I'm trying to access my endpoint url using `http://localhost/inschrijfmodule/wp-json/endpoint/sportivity`

with this code

```
add_action('rest_api_init', function(){
            register_rest_route('endpoint', '/sportivity', [
                'methods' => 'POST',
                'callback' => [$this, 'sportivity_endpoint'],
                'permission_callback' => function () {
                    return true;
                }
            ]);
        });
```

this is the error i'm receiving:

```
{"code":"rest_no_route","message":"No route was found matching the URL and request method","data":{"status":404}}
```

Comment: did you resave/flush permalinks after adding the code? I assume pretty permalinks are enabled and working. Also your permission callback can be simplified to `'permission_callback' => '__return_true'`

Comment: @TomJNowell I resaved the permalinks, they're set on postname. But I still have the same issue

Comment: how did you confirm the code in question actually runs? If you place a `wp_die( 'running' );` inside the function before `register_rest_route` does it die with `running`? You mentioned you used this inside a class but there is no class code in your question. It's also possible that because you used an anonymous function instead of a class method that `$this` doesn't refer to what you expect it to, the solution might be to create a `public function register_rest_routes() : void { ....` class method and call `add_action('rest_api_init', [ $this, 'register_rest_routes' ]...`

Comment: @TomJNowell the `wp_die()` came inside funtion before `register_rest_route`. I also tried your way like here https://pastebin.com/xiyjE8uD but this still does not solves the issue, besides that, it does not trigger the wp_die on the second spot

Comment: so we can confirm `register_rest_route` is being called, can you add any more information about when where and how your class is being used to construct the object? Is it happening in the same file, on `init`, in `functions.php` etc?

Comment: hmm are you testing this by trying to visit it in a browser?

Answer (score 0):

This is why:

```
'methods' => 'POST',
```

Your REST API route is not being found because there is no route at that address that accepts a `GET` request. There is an endpoint with that name that accepts `POST` but it can only be accessed via a `POST` request.

If you want to be able to visit it in a browser via the URL you need to do one of the following:

- `'methods' => 'GET',`
- `'methods' => ['GET, 'POST' ],`

Other things to note:

- In your endpoints callback, use the request object you were given to access the parameters and arguments, do not use `$_POST` or `$_GET`

  - if you access them directly you bypass all the sanitisation and validation security features of the REST API, and have to write extra code to handle GET and POST that WP has already done for you
- `endpoint` is incredibly generic, and there's a good reason the WP endpoints use a version number, this should be changed!
- Anonymous functions like that may look nice but they're awful to debug, don't show up nicely in stack traces, and are a nightmare if you ever have to un-hook/re-hook the callback.
- If you're just using a class as a place to put your functions then you're not doing object oriented programming, and there's no practical difference to functions in a namespace aside from all the extra typing. Save yourself from this turning into the god class anti-pattern

  - a strong indicator of this is if your class has no member variables, is only constructed once, or contains your entire codebase